# No such file or directory found when trying to load image from database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I all,  I have saved my image to the external directory like this:

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Images");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
image = new File(imagesFolder.getPath(), "MyImage_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
```

Then save the image in the database (SQLite) like this:

```
contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_FILEPATH, fileUri.toString());
```

The when loading the image to imageView:

```
String theimage = null;
.....
theimage = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_FILEPATH));
.....
final Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(theimage);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PicView);
image.setImageBitmap(myImage);
```

But when running the app i get this error:

```
01-10 12:12:26.943: E/BitmapFactory(30607): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/Images/MyImage_20150110_121217.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What am i doing wrong here?  I thought that this would get the image and display the image?

Comment: Did you add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your manifest ?

Comment: @Saeed: yes i have as well as read external storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that your images store in `Image` folder

But your problem is `fromFile()` method ,it adds `file://` to the absolute path of your images ,so `BitmapFactory` can't find your images and throw `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Your image address is

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Images/MyImage_1234.jpg
```

instead of

```
/storage/emulated/0/Images/MyImage_1234.jpg
```

Try to change

```
contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_FILEPATH, fileUri.toString());
```

to

```
contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_FILEPATH, image.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, and sorry for the late reply.  I have tried your solution but error message now saying : `01-11 10:37:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18979): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
01-11 10:37:54.783: E/AndroidRuntime(18979):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)`

Comment: @Newbie i edited my answer (change `image.getAbsoluteFile()` to `image.getAbsolutePath()` )

Comment: Thanks, but am getting a null pointer exception now once the image has been taken and returning to the app.

Comment: @Newbie it works for me. Are your images stored in `/storage/emulated/0/Images/`?

Comment: Yes, however i think I know what the issue is.  The imageview is actually in a layoutinflater view.  So when i just display the image in an imageView i created within the activity then the image is displayed, but when trying to load the image in the imageView which is in the Layoutinflater then it crashes.  But when i add `View view  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
      ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.PicView);` and then the rest of the code then the app doesn't crashes, but then nothing is displayed.

Comment: So I will mark your answer as correct and then move on to the next issue of displaying the image in the LayoutInflater. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `new File()`, doesn't create a file. It creates a pointer to that location.

You need to use an OutputStream to save that file:

```
// Open file
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Images");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
File image = new File(imagesFolder.getPath(), "MyImage_.jpg");

// Create it if it doesn't exist
if (!image.exists()) {
    try {
        // Create file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        outputStream.write("Hello".getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        // Save ABSOLUTE_PATH to DB
        contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_FILEPATH, image.getAbsolutePath());
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then fetch the path from DB and use

```
String absPath = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_FILEPATH));
final Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absPath);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I have tried your solution, but doesn't seem to work, now i think the problem might be is when i return from the camera intent it displays a thumbnail image of the image taken by the camera intent. I think when trying to load the image from that path it tries to display the full sized image?  I don't know if my theory is right but worth asking.